# withRouter not working correctly with redux - react redux react-router

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

This is my initial state in `authReducer`.

```
const initialState = {
    token:'',
    isLogin:  false,
    error: {}
};
function AuthReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type){
        case AUTH_SUCCESS:
            return sessionStorage.setItem('token',action.payload),{
                ...state,
                isLogin: true,
                token: action.payload,
                error: {}
            };
        case AUTH_FAILED:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLogin: false,
                token: '',
                error: action.payload
            };
            default:
            return state
    }
}
export default AuthReducer;
```

This is my login component that works fine. User can authenticate and everything is working fine:

```
class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            username: '',
            password: ''
        }
    }
    onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        this.props.login(this.state.username, this.state.password);
    }
    
    render() {
       .....
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        get: { auth : state.AuthReducer}
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        login: (username, password) => {
            return dispatch(login(username, password));
        }
    };
}
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login));
```

And my router is something like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }
  render() {
    let PrivateRoute = ({ component: ChildComponent, isLogin, ...rest}) => {
      console.log({...rest}, "this is rest")
      return <Route 
      {...rest}
        render={props => {
          if (!isLogin) {
            return <Redirect to="/login" />;
        } else {
          return <ChildComponent {...props} />
        }
      }} />
    }
    return (
      <div>
          <Home />
          <Switch>
          <PrivateRoute path="/" exact isLogin={this.props.auth.isLogin}  component={mainContent} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/posts" isLogin={this.props.auth.isLogin} component={Posts} />
          <Route path="/login"  component={Login} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    auth: state.AuthReducer
  }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    getUser: () => {
      return dispatch(getUser());
    }
  };
}
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App));
```

In react-router, they said you must use `withRouter` from react-router-dom. my problem is login works fine. but I don't have access to my props in my `privateroute` so when react renders a new page my `isLogin` sets to false. I have some idea that router doesn't know about my redux or protected components cant are not aware of changes in props.all of my child components in my `PrivateRoute` are connected with react-redux.

Answer (score 0):

Here the issue is you are not getting isLogin value from reducer. When you try to get reducer value in your router file:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    auth: state.AuthReducer
  }
}
```

You will get `this.props.auth.AuthReducer` as undefined as the `state` value in mapStateToProps will be your initial value from your reducer. So, either you can get Login from state directly like below and try to access `this.props.auth`:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    auth: state.isLogin
  };
};
```

or you can replace you code with this and use `this.props.auth.isLogin`:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    auth: state
  };
};
```

Refer this for more:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-dom-with-private-route-sr61v